# Determinant over a specific axis using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, determinants

Suppose I have a numpy array A with shape (j,d,d) and I want to obtain an array with shape j, in which each entry corresponds to the determinant of each (d,d) array.

I tried using `np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.det(A), axis=0)`, but `np.apply_along_axis` only seems to work for 1D slices.

Is there an efficient way of doing that using only numpy?

Comment: Does `np.linalg.det(A)` not work for you? `det(A)[0] == det(A[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.linalg.det` can already do this for an array of arbitrary shape as long as the last two dimensions are square. You can see the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html).